# Existence and uniqueness of limit of inverse function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $f:(a,b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a one to one function. If $x_0$ is a point of the open interval $(a,b)$ such that $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} f(x) = l$, is it necessary that $\lim_{x \rightarrow l} f^{-1}(x) = x_0$?

My guess is no. I have found out pretty interesting things for cases where $x_0$ is either $a$ or $b$ or where the domain is not an interval, but i can't arrive to a final conclusion about the interval case. I am asking about general functions, the only nice property I assume is that the domain is an interval, i.e. I don't expect continuity or even boundedness.

So, if this holds, I need a proof and possibly a reference to some textbook. If this doesn't, I want a counterexample. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: What about $f=tan$ and $x_0=\frac{\pi}{2}$ as a counterexample?

Comment: @mak: For $tan(x)$, the limit does not exist in $\frac{\pi}2$. At least not in the definition of limit: A limit exists when left and right limit are finite and equal.

Comment: @StevePap: You just started off by saying that $x_0$  is in the open interval $(a, b)$. Then $x_0$  can't be $a$  or $b$.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux yes I got it backwards.
What about $f^{-1} = tan$ and $x_0=\infty$ ?

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux I know what I said. I just added that in other cases things are interesting.

Comment: @mak: No, because if $l=\infty$, than the limit did not exist. Because it is not finite.

Comment: @mak $\infty$ cannot be a point of an open interval but you're not very clear in any case.

Comment: @StevePap true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so this is pretty horrid, but define $f:(-1,1)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in the following way:

$f(x) = x$ for $x \leq 0$.
For $\frac{1}{2}\geq x >0$, $f(x) = x + \frac{1}{2^n}$, where $\frac{1}{2^n}$ is smallest such that $\frac{1}{2^n} \geq x$.  This leaves a bunch of "gaps" near zero which are not in the image of $f$ yet.
For $\frac{1}{2} < x < 1$, $f(x) = x -\frac{1}{2}$ if $x - \frac{1}{2}$ is not already in the range of $f$.
There are continuum many remaining values of $x$ (where $f(x)$ is not yet defined), biject them with the rest of $\mathbb{R}$ in any way you like.

Then $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x) = 0$, but $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}f^{-1}(x)$ does not exist as, for any $\delta>0$, $f^{-1}(x)$ takes on values arbitrarily close to $0$ and to $\frac{1}{2}$ for $x \in (-\delta, \delta)$.

Comment: Oh my God, horrid? This is wonderful! Thanks a lot for your time, this was VERY clarifying and intriguing!

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the previous answer. We can write the following function
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases} 
    x                                   &\quad\text{if } x \leq 0 \\
    x + 2^{\lceil \log_2 x \rceil}    &\quad\text{if } 0 < x \leq \frac{1}{2} \\
    (x - \frac{1}{2}) + 2^{\lceil \log_2 (x - \frac{1}{2}) \rceil - 1}      &\quad\text{if } \frac{1}{2} < x \leq 1 \\
    x                                   &\quad\text{if } x > 1 \\
\end{cases}
$$

I graphed this function [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nppru.png). This function is bijective, so has a well-defined inverse $f^{-1}$.

Clearly from the graph, we can see that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = 0$. However, $\lim_{y \rightarrow 0} f^{-1}(y)$ is undefined since it oscillates between $0$ and $\frac{1}{2}$.